Recreating a Heatmap in R
I am working with the R programming language.
I found these plots that I really like (https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10902-020-00307-8) and want to try and recreate them:

Using the following link (https://jkzorz.github.io/2020/02/29/contour-plots.html), I tried to simulate some data and recreate the plots:
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
library(metR)

set.seed(123)  
Biomass <- seq(0, 10, length.out = 100)
variable <- seq(0, 10, length.out = 100)

con <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = length(variable), nrow = length(Biomass)))

for (i in 1:length(Biomass)) {
    for (j in 1:length(variable)) {
        con[i, j] <- sin(Biomass[i]) + cos(variable[j])  # adjust this as needed
    }
}

rownames(con) <- Biomass

con <- cbind(Biomass = rownames(con), con)
rownames(con) <- NULL

con$Biomass <- as.numeric(con$Biomass)



conm = melt(con, id = "Biomass")
conm$variable <- gsub("X", "", conm$variable)
conm$variable = as.numeric(conm$variable)
gg = ggplot(conm, aes(x = variable, y = Biomass)) + 
    geom_raster(aes(fill = value)) + 
    geom_contour(aes(z = value), colour = "white", size = 0.2, alpha = 0.5) + 
    geom_text_contour(aes(z = value),  colour = "white" ) +
    labs(x = "Filtered light intensity (umol photons/m2/s)", 
         y = "Dry Biomass Concentration (g/L)", 
         fill = "Productivity (umol O2/g biomass/s)") + 
    theme(legend.title = element_text(size = 10, face = "bold"), 
          legend.position = "top", panel.background = element_blank(), 
          axis.text = element_text(colour = "black", size = 10, face = "bold"), 
          axis.title = element_text(size = 12, face = "bold"), 
          legend.text = element_text(size = 11), legend.key = element_blank()) + 
    scale_fill_continuous(low = "#BFE1B0", high = "#137177") + 
    scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0)) +
    scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0,0)) 

gg


Is it possible to recreate the color scheme?
Thanks!

The color scheme looks like the RdYlGn palette available in the package RColorBrewer. To use that palette for your continuous data, you can create a function that interpolates the the color values:
my_colors <- colorRampPalette(RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(11, "RdYlGn"))
Overwriting the fill aesthetic in your example gives a good approximation of the colors of the reference figure:
gg + scale_fill_gradientn(colors = my_colors(10))


You can use scale_fill_distiller from RColorBrewer package to obtain the desired fill pallette. The direction argument controls the order in which the palette is rendered from low to high values, 1 is from red to green, while -1 is from green to red.
library(RColorBrewer)
gg + scale_fill_distiller(palette = "RdYlGn", direction = 1)


